# TFS not recognising files are not downloaded

Tags: .net, visual-studio, tfs

I have deleted a bunch of folders on my local workspace, however, TFS still thinks I have them so "Get Latest" is not working.

I can't use "Get Specific" because this needs to be part of a script used by the team.

How can I tell TFS to look at my workspace again and notice that the files are there?

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify which version of TFS you're using, but we can assume from your question that you're *not* using the new "local workspace" feature, else you'd not have this issue. If you have TFS 2012/13, working with a [local workspace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb892960%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) may be of benefit to you.

If you're stuck with server workspaces, you have little by way of choice. Basically, either:

1. don't delete the folders locally; delete them through TFS so that it can track the change (note: I suspect this isn't what you want, since you seem to be trying to get the content back)
2. use "get specific" (really this is the answer, but you don't explain *why* you can't use this in a script - I believe `tf get /force` will do the job.)
3. delete and re-get the whole workspace